# Trying to get a list of "tables" in an excel document

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel document that has a couple of tables (selected the data and chose format as a table and gave it a name).

I am trying to open the workbook and get all the tables inside the document.

The following code returns a bunch of sections from the workbook but doesn't return the specific tables.

Is this possible?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataSet _excelDataSet;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var filePath = "c:\\temp\\orderforms\\SampleOrder.xlsx";

        var tmpName = Path.GetTempFileName() + Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        File.Copy(filePath, tmpName);
        filePath = tmpName;


        var excelReader = GetExcelDataReader(filePath, true);
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

        _excelDataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet();

    }

    private static IExcelDataReader GetExcelDataReader(string path, bool isFirstRowAsColumnNames)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            IExcelDataReader dataReader;

            if (path.EndsWith(".xls"))
                dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream);
            else if (path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileStream);
            else
                throw new FileToBeProcessedIsNotInTheCorrectFormatException("The file to be processed is not an Excel file");

            dataReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = isFirstRowAsColumnNames;

            return dataReader;
        }
    }

    private void btnLoadOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt1 = _excelDataSet.Tables[Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)];

        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
        MessageBox.Show(dt1.TableName);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
excel.FileName = "c:\\temp\\orderforms\\orderform.xlsx";
var order = from x in excel.NamedRange<SunglassesOrder>("Order")
                     where x.Qty!=""
                     select x;
dataGridView1.DataSource = order.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

use linqtoexcel library. Example can easily be found on how to use this library.

Comment: Thanks Jaykumar,
This is my working version
            var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory();
            excel.FileName = "c:\\temp\\orderforms\\my order form.xlsx";
            var order = from x in excel.NamedRange<SunglassesOrder>("Order")
                         where x.Qty!=""
                         select x;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = order.ToList();